everything inside mat-form-field tag is invisible in Angular CLI version 16 using the @angular/material package
This is how the website looks like when i boot it up:


Whenever i click on one of the form fields this happens but i dont know how or why this happens, i did try to inspect element and still to no avail:

Here is the html code:
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Login as {{ userRole | titlecase }}</h2>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <form (ngSubmit)="login()">
    <div class="form-container">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter your username" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username" required>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter your password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" name="passWord" [(ngModel)]="passWord" required>
        <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field *ngIf="userRole === 'artist'">
        <mat-label>Authentication Id</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Authentication ID" [(ngModel)]="authentication_id" name="authentication_id" required/>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
      <button mat-raised-button type="submit">Log In</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

and here is the css code:
form {
    max-width: 400px; /* Set a max width for the form */ 
}
  
.form-group {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add spacing between fields */
}

label {
    flex: 1; /* Make the label take up one part of the row */
    text-align: right; /* Align text to the right */
    margin-right: 10px; /* Add spacing between label and input */
}

input {

    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-color: blueviolet;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 150%;
}

button {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: chartreuse;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer
}

hr {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

form {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
}

.form-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    .mdc-text-field {
        background-color: blue !important;
    }
}
  
.form-container > * {
    width: 100%;

    .mdc-text-field {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    }

    .mat-mdc-form-field-ripple::before {
        opacity: 1 !important; /* Ensure the line is always visible */
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42) !important; /* Optional: Adjust color for better visibility */
    }
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex; /* Make it a flex container */
    justify-content: center; /* Center horizontally */
    align-items: center; /* Center vertically */
}

.mat-mdc-raised-button {
    background-color: rgb(0, 115, 255) !important;

    .mdc-button__label {
        color: white;
    }
    
}

.mdc-text-field {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}

The Field form had initially a grey background but I changed it to a white one instead, I still can not pinpoint the styles for the other elements in the form so I can change their colours as well.

have you upgrade the version of project?
